# Reporting robust means and SD to make more comparable to robustbase::glmrob results

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, mean, robust, huber

I need to report the mean, and SD of two groups for a specific variable, as well as the odds ratio of the two groups using robust logistic regression. The variable does have outliers. I instead want to report the robust mean and sd with a method that is similarly used in the robust logistic regression.

I simply want to get the new robust calculated mean and SD of the first term using the same methods from `robustbase::glmrob` R function. Method is default (method="Mqle") and family=binomial(link = "logit"). I calculated the Huber M-estimator of the mean and SD using `MASS::hubers(x, k=1.3450)` but I am not sure this is the estimator method used in `robustbase::glmrob`. Do you know what method is used and how I can use that method to calculate the robust mean and SD in R? Based on reading the original papers, it seems that to get a robust estimator of variance, they choose a simple M-estimator (Huber’s proposal 2). This variance estimator is calculated using `MASS::hubers()`, not `MASS::huber()`. The latter is based on the median absolute deviation (MAD) scale. However, glmrob does not seem to use a robust mean in the formulas. I still believe its better to report robust means and SD so that the summary stats and models are more comparable.

method="Mqle" fits a generalized linear model using Mallows (Mallows quasi-likelihood estimator) or Huber type robust estimators, as described in Cantoni and Ronchetti (2001) and Cantoni and Ronchetti (2006).

*Eva Cantoni and Elvezio Ronchetti (2001) Robust Inference for Generalized Linear Models. JASA 96 (455), 1022–1030.*

*Eva Cantoni and Elvezio Ronchetti (2006) A robust approach for skewed and heavy-tailed outcomes in the analysis of health care expenditures. Journal of Health Economics 25, 198–213.*

Here is an example:

Here is an example dataframe with a binomial response variable "Group", a numeric variable and covariable.

```
> df <- data.frame(group = as.factor(c(rep(1, 10), rep(2,10))),
           variable = c(2,6,1,2,2,2,4,0,2,6,7,19,5,6,0,10,5,2,5,0),
           covariable = c(19,22,16,18,18,19,19,15,18,13,16,16,19,17, 21,12,14,19,18,18)
)

> df

   group variable covariable
1      1        2         19
2      1        6         22
3      1        1         16
4      1        2         18
5      1        2         18
6      1        2         19
7      1        4         19
8      1        0         15
9      1        2         18
10     1        6         13
11     2        7         16
12     2       19         16
13     2        5         19
14     2        6         17
15     2        0         21
16     2       10         12
17     2        5         14
18     2        2         19
19     2        5         18
20     2        0         18
```

Calculate the standard mean and SD

```
> aggregate(variable ~ group, df, function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
  
group   variable.mean variable.sd
1     1           2.7         2.0
2     2           5.9         5.6
```

Using robust logistic regression. Notice that rows 15 and 20 are outliers and are thus weighted. These outliers are due to the variable, not covariable. I know this because the weights hardly changed when I removed the covariable term.

```
> robustbase::glmrob(group ~ variable + covariable  , data=df, family = binomial(link = "logit")) %>% summary()

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.264760   4.218720  -0.300    0.764
variable     0.280474   0.208623   1.344    0.179
covariable   0.006005   0.220648   0.027    0.978
Robustness weights w.r * w.x: 
 18 weights are ~= 1. The remaining 2 ones are
    15     20 
0.7611 0.7543 

Number of observations: 20 
Fitted by method ‘Mqle’  (in 7 iterations)

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

No deviance values available 
Algorithmic parameters: 
   acc    tcc 
0.0001 1.3450 
maxit 
   50 
test.acc 
  "coef"
```

Calculate the Huber M-estimator of the mean and "SD". Notice that the mean and SDs are different from the original. I "think" that the same M-estimator method used in MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450) to estimate the mean and variance is used in `glmrob(method="Mqle")` function. If not, please correct me.

```
> aggregate(variable ~ group, df, function(y) c(mean.h = MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450)$mu, sd.h = MASS::hubers(y, k=1.3450)$s))
  group variable.mean.h  variable.sd.h
      1             2.6            2.2
      2             5.1            4.4
```

Comment: To myself: do yourself and the reviewers a favor by simply reporting the median (Q1, Q3) if you are worried about outliers when summarizing variables :)